# Calculating Percentage Error in the Ratio when there is an Error in Numerator or Denominator or both ?

Tags: ratio, error-propagation

I have serached google a bit, but Since Google searches for keywords and also I find it hard to put in a statement for which It can give me useful searches, I am asking it here. So, This is Question of **`Error Calculation in Ratios`**

So, Let's say we have to calculate some ratio for precise calculations and terms being involved in the ratio be `x` and `y`. Accordingly, $$ Ratio = \frac{x}{y}$$

While calculating , some error was noticed, that can be expressed as $ \Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ respectively for error in measuring Numerator and Denominator values.

Now we need to find the `error change in ratio` and `% Error Change in Ratio`. So, the problem can be broken down into these subproblems :

1. When Only Numerator changes by $\Delta x $ that is $ Ratio = \frac {x+\Delta x}{y}$
2. When Only Denominator changes by $\Delta y$ that is $ Ratio = \frac {x}{y+\Delta y}$
3. When both Numerator & Denominator changes simultaneously by $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ respectively that is $ Ratio = \frac {x+\Delta x}{y+\Delta y}$

Consider both increase and decrease scenario for the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r=\frac xy$. Then, $$dr = \frac{ydx-xdy}{y^2}$$

This is the error change in $r$, given the values $x,y$ and the error changes (with +ve sign for increase and -ve sign for decrease) in both of them.

The maximum fractional error is simply:

$$\frac{dr}{r}=\frac{\frac{ydx-xdy}{y^2}}{\frac xy}=\frac{ydx-xdy}{xy}$$

Can you proceed now?

---

**EDIT:** For case 1, denominator does not change. So in that case $dy=0$. Similarly, in case 2, numerator does not change. So in that case $dx=0$.

**Example problem:** if $x=5\pm0.05$ and $y=6$, what would you expect $dr$ and $dr/r$ to be?

Here, $x = 5, y = 6$. Also, $y$ is *exactly* known, so $dy=0$ but $dx=0.05\neq0$. Now you can put and solve.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you please elaborate it for each case as I mentioned in the question. Also an example will clarify much more.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus Have a look!

Comment: Just one last thing. How do I calculate %error for all of this ? and Also, What does maximum fractional error implies ?

Comment: %error is simply "(fractional error*100)%". I used the term maximum fractional error, though other books will only use "fractional error". The thing is that the instruments (ruler, screw gauge, etc.), measuring these quantities $x$ and $y$, are error prone. But, we do *not* know exactly how _much_ error there might be. There might be some error, or no error at all. Thus, the quantity given in $\pm da$ is usually the maximum fractional error in $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Gaurang's answer above says that for a fixed error dx in x, you can improve your uncertainty on r by *increasing* your uncertainty in y. That can't be correct.

The taylor expansion is correct, but then you have to add the *variances*, and the variance of (-xdy) = +x^2\sigma_y. This yields the well known sum of quadratures formula:

(dr/r)^2 = (dx/x)^2 + (dy/y)^2,

Same as above but definitely no minus!